# How to get username value into welcome page after entering in login page through servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets

Below is the login page:

**index.html**

```html
    <div class="container " >
    <h2  align="center" >Account Login</h2><br>

    <form action="servlet1" method="post"> 
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="Username">
      </div> <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userPass" placeholder="Password">

        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <br> 
    <span id="spanbut"><input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary"  /> </span> 
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Below is the servlet which checks if username and password match. Username and password is hard coded. If they match, user is navigated to welcome page.

**Login.java**

```java
    import java.io.*;  
    import javax.servlet.*;  
    import javax.servlet.http.*;  
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;  
    @WebServlet("/servlet1")  
    public class Login extends HttpServlet {  

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String n=request.getParameter("userName");  
        String p=request.getParameter("userPass");  

        String[][] arr = new String [4][4];
        arr[0][0] = "ABC";
        arr[0][1] = "Password123";
        arr[1][0] = "XYZ";
        arr[1][1] = "servlet";
        arr[2][0] = "PQR";
        arr[2][1] = "Outlook123";
        arr[3][0] = "TUV";
        arr[3][1] = "Hello123";
        boolean flag=false;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            if(n.equals(arr[i][0]))
            {
                if(p.equals(arr[i][1]))
                {

                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2");  
                    rd.forward(request, response); 
                    flag =true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(flag==false)
        {
            //out.print("Sorry UserName or Password Error!");  
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("incorrect.html");  
            rd.include(request, response); 
        }  

    }}
```

I must get the username value to the welcome page through html. 
Below is the servlet which is getting called for the welcome page. 
Do I need a servlet for this?

**WelcomeServlet.java**

```java
    @WebServlet("/servlet2")
    public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {  

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

        String n=request.getParameter("userName");  
        out.print("Welcome "+n);  

        }  

    }
```

Comment: use setAttribute and getAttribute  https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/requestsetattribute.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can get `username` by using *[request.getAttribute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String))* & *[request.setAttribute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))* . Like below :

```
       if(n.equals(arr[i][0]))
            {
                if(p.equals(arr[i][1]))
                {
                      //get username if password and username matched
                   String username1=a[i][0];
                   //set username1 in request
                    request.setAttribute("username", username1); 
                    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2");  
                    rd.forward(request, response); 
                    flag =true;
                }
            }
```

And then in your `WelcomeServlet` do like below :

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
            throws ServletException, IOException {  

        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
           //getting value got from Login servlet
        String n=(String)request.getAttribute("username");  
        out.print("Welcome "+n);  

        }
```